# An easy way to compute $\int ^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos(x\sqrt{e-1})}{xe^x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Is there any other way yet simple to compute  this integral : $$\int ^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos(x\sqrt{e-1})}{xe^x}dx$$

What i saw as first lines of the solution :
\begin{align}
\int ^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos(x\sqrt{e-1})}{xe^x}dx&=\int ^\infty_0e^{-x}\left(\frac{1-\cos(x\sqrt{e-1})}{x}\right)dx\\
&=\int^\infty_0e^{-x}\int^{\sqrt{e-1}}_0\sin(xy) \ dy \ dx\\
&=\int^\infty_0\int^{\sqrt{e-1}}_0e^{-x}\sin(xy)dydx
\end{align}

Comment: This technique can be made much more concise viz.$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos kx}{xe^x}dx=\int_0^kdy\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin xy}{e^x}dx=\int_0^k\frac{ydy}{1+y^2}=\tfrac12\ln(1+k^2).$$I have no idea why it took [Michael Penn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJzIZNvscpM) so long.

Comment: Indeed, [Wolfie](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Ccos%5Cleft%28x%5Csqrt%7Be-1%7D%5Cright%29%7D%7Bxe%5E%7Bx%7D%7D+from+0+to+infinity), short for Wolfram Alpha, seems to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Schwinger parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization). If you rewrite $\frac1x$ as $\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}dy$, with $k:=\sqrt{e-1}$ you get$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty dy\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos kx}{e^{x(y+1)}}dx&=\int_0^\infty dy\left(\tfrac{1}{y+1}-\tfrac{y+1}{k^2+(y+1)^2}\right)\\&=-\tfrac12\left[\ln\left(1+\tfrac{k^2}{(y+1)^2}\right)\right]_0^\infty\\&=\tfrac12\ln(1+k^2).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

A generalization, due to Ramanujan who worked with Frullani-type integrals is
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-a x}\cos{(A x)} - e^{-bx}\cos{(B x)}}{x} \ dx = 
-\frac{1}{2}\log{\frac{a^2+A^2}{b^2+B^2}} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{k \equiv \root{\expo{} - 1} > 0}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \cos\pars{kx} \over x\expo{x}}
\,\dd x} =
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{x^{-1}\expo{-x} - x^{-1}
\expo{\pars{\ic k - 1}x}}\,\dd x
\end{align}
Lets consider
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\nu - 1}\expo{\ic \alpha x}\dd x =
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\nu - 1}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\alpha^{n}\expo{-\ic n\pi/2}}\,
{\pars{-x}^{n} \over n!}\dd x =
\Gamma\pars{\nu}\bracks{\alpha^{-\nu}\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2}}
\end{align}
where I used the
[Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansMasterTheorem.html).
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \cos\pars{kx} \over x\expo{x}}
\,\dd x} =
\Re\braces{\lim_{\nu \to 0}\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{\nu}\ic^{-\nu}\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2} -
\Gamma\pars{\nu}\pars{k + \ic}^{-\nu}\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\braces{\lim_{\nu \to 0}\totald{\bracks{%
\ic^{-\nu}\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2} -
\pars{k + \ic}^{-\nu}\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2}}}{\nu}
}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\bracks{-\,{\pi \over 2}\,\ic + \ln\pars{k + \ic}} =
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 + k^{2}} = \bbx{\large{1 \over 2}} \\ &
\end{align}